# Assertion Error When Accessing Struct Field

Tags: rust, llvm

I'm trying to declare a global variable, who's type is a struct with a function pointer and a char pointer element `{ i64 ()*, i8* }`, and then set the fields to null during `main`, but I'm getting an assertion error using a debug version of LLVM.

```
/media/work/contrib/llvm-project/llvm/lib/IR/ConstantsContext.h:745: void llvm::ConstantUniqueMap<ConstantClass>::remove(ConstantClass*) [with ConstantClass = llvm::ConstantExpr]: Assertion `I != Map.end() && "Constant not found in constant table!"' failed.
```

I believe this problem is causing another issue during optimization when compiling something a bit more complicated. The error itself occurs when disposing of the module at the end.  A distilled runnable example in rust is:

```
use std::ffi::CString;

extern crate llvm_sys;
pub use self::llvm_sys::prelude::{ LLVMValueRef };
use self::llvm_sys::*;
use self::llvm_sys::prelude::*;
use self::llvm_sys::core::*;
use self::llvm_sys::target::*;
use self::llvm_sys::target_machine::*;
use self::llvm_sys::transforms::pass_manager_builder::*;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let context = LLVMContextCreate();
        let module = LLVMModuleCreateWithName(cstr("module"));
        build(module, context);
        println!("{}", emit_module(module));
        LLVMDisposeModule(module);
        LLVMContextDispose(context);
    }
}

pub fn cstr(string: &str) -> *mut i8 {
    CString::new(string).unwrap().into_raw()
}

pub unsafe fn build(module: LLVMModuleRef, context: LLVMContextRef) {
    let builder = LLVMCreateBuilderInContext(context);

    let mut argtypes = vec!();
    let func_type = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt64TypeInContext(context), argtypes.as_mut_ptr(), argtypes.len() as u32, false as i32);
    let fptr_type = LLVMPointerType(func_type, 0);

    let context_type = LLVMPointerType(LLVMInt8TypeInContext(context), 0);

    let mut structfields = vec!(fptr_type, context_type);
    let struct_type = LLVMStructType(structfields.as_mut_ptr(), structfields.len() as u32, false as i32);

    let initializer = LLVMConstNull(struct_type);
    let global = LLVMAddGlobal(module, struct_type, cstr("function"));
    LLVMSetInitializer(global, initializer);
    LLVMSetLinkage(global, LLVMLinkage::LLVMExternalLinkage);

    let mut argtypes = vec!();
    let main_type = LLVMFunctionType(LLVMInt64TypeInContext(context), argtypes.as_mut_ptr(), argtypes.len() as u32, false as i32);
    let function = LLVMAddFunction(module, cstr("main"), main_type);

    let bb = LLVMAppendBasicBlockInContext(context, function, cstr("entry"));
    LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, bb);

    let mut indices = vec!(LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32TypeInContext(context), 0, 0), LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt32TypeInContext(context), 0, 0));
    let field = LLVMBuildGEP(builder, global, indices.as_mut_ptr(), indices.len() as u32, cstr(""));
    LLVMBuildStore(builder, LLVMConstNull(fptr_type), field);

    LLVMBuildRet(builder, LLVMConstInt(LLVMInt64TypeInContext(context), 0, 0));

    LLVMDisposeBuilder(builder);
}

pub fn emit_module(module: LLVMModuleRef) -> String {
    unsafe { CString::from_raw(LLVMPrintModuleToString(module)).into_string().unwrap() }
}
```

The full output is:

```
; ModuleID = 'module'
source_filename = "module"

@function = global { i64 ()*, i8* } zeroinitializer

define i64 @main() {
entry:
  store i64 ()* null, i64 ()** getelementptr inbounds ({ i64 ()*, i8* }, { i64 ()*, i8* }* @function, i32 0, i32 0), align 8
  ret i64 0
}

/media/work/contrib/llvm-project/llvm/lib/IR/ConstantsContext.h:745: void llvm::ConstantUniqueMap<ConstantClass>::remove(ConstantClass*) [with ConstantClass = llvm::ConstantExpr]: Assertion `I != Map.end() && "Constant not found in constant table!"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the issue is.  In the example above, the function `LLVMStructType()` also has an alternate version `LLVMStructTypeInContext()`, which if used instead will fix the assertion error.  There is also another function `LLVMModuleCreateWithNameInContext`, which should probably be used instead, but in the example above, it will work without fixing this.

It's also possible to replace all the `InContext` versions with their non-context versions to fix the problem in the example

In my actual program, removing the `InContext` versions didn't work for some reason, but the two non-context functions mentioned above were being used, as well a couple uses of the non-context `LLVMAppendBasicBlock`.  Replacing these with the `InContext` version fixed all the assertion errors, include the one that started this:

```
void llvm::Value::doRAUW(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value::ReplaceMetadataUses): Assertion `New->getType() == getType() && "replaceAllUses of value with new value of different type!"' failed.
```

The type pointers weren't the same, so it must have been because they were defined in different contexts.